# Python Parallel Function to find value in iterable using multiprocessing

Tags: python, algorithm, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to create a function to find the index of a value in an iterable. It uses the linear search algorithm but applies it on four parts of the iterable simultaneously. I won't actually use this function; I am just trying to learn multiprocessing.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def search(l, x):
  processes : int = min(4, len(l))

  #function to find value
  def find(l,x) -> int:
    for i,v in enumerate(l):
      if v==x:
        return i

  args : genarator = ((v,x) for v in l)

  with Pool(processes) as p:
    #apply function on 4 quarters of the iterable, parallelely

    res : list = p.starmap(find, args, chunksize=len(l)/processes)

  return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
  #test example
  print(search([14, 73,64,13,781], 64))
```

This script doesn't output anything nor raise any error. What could the problem be?

Comment: @YvesDaoust My question is why it isn't working as intended. I forgot asking that sorry.

Comment: Meta: I hate it when a question is closed just as I'm finishing up typing an answer...

Comment: @MichaelButscher OP has edited it – "This script doesn't output anything nor raises any error."

Comment: whats a "genarator"'?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki It's a typo.

Comment: Typos in code, not in comments can be fatal. Luckily python doesn't really care about what type of variable you write, so some amount of typos are allowed in code.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki That's very beside the point here, don't you think? And anyway, Python _does_ care about types, it just doesn't parse annotations at runtime.

Comment: Anyway, since this doesn't seem to get reopened, here's the answer I would've posted, would be a shame for it to just get /dev/null'd: https://gist.github.com/akx/2e3b4183315b2cf11f05a8000477f4fd

Comment: @AKX In your solution you forgot to declare `jobs` as a genarator

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments aren't exactly correct, especially regarding the `chunksize` parameter (which tells `multiprocessing` how many jobs to send to each worker in one go, to avoid serialization inefficiencies).

You'd need to do something like below (i.e. tell each worker what range they're working on), but since this will involve starting subprocesses, copying a (presumably large) list into them, and having no early-out mechanism (stopping other workers in case one of the workers finds the value), it'll likely end up being pretty inefficient time-and-memory-wise.

Another approach (that'd pipe less data to the subprocesses) would be to slice the list in the parent.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def find(lst, value_to_find, start: int, end: int) -> int | None:
    for index, v in enumerate(lst[start:end]):
        if v == value_to_find:
            return index + start


def search(lst, value_to_find):
    processes: int = min(4, len(lst))
    with Pool(processes) as p:
        chunk_size = len(lst) // processes
        jobs = (
            (
                lst,
                value_to_find,
                i * chunk_size,  # start
                (i + 1) * chunk_size,  # end
            ) for i in range(processes)
        )
        for res in p.starmap(find, jobs):
            if res is not None:
                return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(search(list(reversed(range(10_000))), 7423))
```